# PHP call_user_func with class and arguments

Tags: php, callback

I need to use call_user_func  . I will need to call a function in a separate file in separate class with 5 arguments . I couldnt find any example  here http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php . IS there any way to do this ?

Comment: Of course there is. What have you tried? Did it work? If not, what happened instead?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Personally I use `call_user_func_array`.

`$result = call_user_func_array(array($objectInstance, 'objectMethod'), array('parameter one', 'parameter two'));`

If the method is a static one, replace `$objectInstance` with the name of the class being used. You can also use stand-alone functions too:

`$result = call_user_func_array('functionName', array('parameter one', 'parameter two'));`

Hope this makes sense? :]

However in the future, try and show us what you have and haven't done :]

Comment: `call_user_func_array` is the best! :)