# Best way to Convert array of arrays into single array

Tags: php

I want to convert

```
$array_of_arrays = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8],[9,10]];
```

Into

```
 $array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
```

I can use

```
    $array = [];
 foreach($array_of_arrays as $one_array):
    $array = array_merge($array,$one_array);
   endforeach;
```

But i have very long array of arrays, is there any function(method) exists for doing this without foreach loop

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `call_user_func_array` function:

```
$array_of_arrays = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8],[9,10]];
$result = call_user_func_array("array_merge", $array_of_arrays);
print_r($result);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
    [4] => 5
    [5] => 6
    [6] => 7
    [7] => 8
    [8] => 9
    [9] => 10
)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `array_merge` with `call_user_func_array`:

```
$res = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $array_of_arrays);
var_dump($res);

array(10) {
  [0] =>
  int(1)
  [1] =>
  int(2)
  [2] =>
  int(3)
  [3] =>
  int(4)
  [4] =>
  int(5)
  [5] =>
  int(6)
  [6] =>
  int(7)
  [7] =>
  int(8)
  [8] =>
  int(9)
  [9] =>
  int(10)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**// Use of array_merge with call_user_func_array**

```
        $array_of_arrays = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8],[9,10]];  
        $oneDimensionalArray = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $array_of_arrays);
        print_r( $oneDimensionalArray);
```

// Output will be: Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 [3] => 4 [4] => 5 [5] => 6 [6] => 7 [7] => 8 [8] => 9 [9] => 10 )

// Read more about call_user_func_array() [PHP call_user_func with class and arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11780551/php-call-user-func-with-class-and-arguments)